# findViewById() in extends subclass

Tags: java, android, class, android-view

I have two classes like:

```
public class Game extends Activity

public class CoreGame extends Game
```

In **CoreGame** class I have:

```
public void init(){
    layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlayout);
}
```

The execution return `NullPointerException` at `layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlayout);` **CoreGame** class line.

Why?

The OnCreate :

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        core = new CoreGame(this);
        core.runCoreGame();

    }
```

The Core.runCoreGame():

```
public void runCoreGame(){
    init();
}

public void init(){
    layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlayout);
}
```

The StackTrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gianbalex.mgs_revenge/gianbalex.mgs_revenge.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1637)
        at gianbalex.mgs_revenge.CoreGame.initVariables(CoreGame.java:118)
        at gianbalex.mgs_revenge.CoreGame.runCoreGame(CoreGame.java:84)
        at gianbalex.mgs_revenge.Game.onCreate(Game.java:28)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: From where are you calling init()?

Comment: Post your stack trace (logcat)

Comment: There is very little information here, so it is going to be nearly impossible to help. Can you show us the rest of the code?

Comment: So we can see what's wrong. Also, use comments for responses. if you edit your post for responses, we will never see them.

Comment: Are you calling init() from a constructor? If so, you need to move that to `onCreate()`.

Comment: @DavidWasser is correct. Your constructor is instantiated by the Android system. Doing anything in the constructor is highly discouraged as the entity (activity, application, service) is in a null state. Nothing has been done to it and it has no knowledge of it environment.

Comment: @AedonEtLira see my stacktrace

Comment: @RaghavSood i call init from OnCreate void of Game class like this:

CoreGame core = new CoreGame();

core.init()

Comment: @GianfilippoBalestriero Post the onCreate()

Comment: @GianfilippoBalestriero You never, Never, NEVER create an Activity on your own. The system does this for you. I recommend reviewing the Activity lifecycle for android before you continue.

Comment: @RaghavSood i've post the onCreate()

Comment: @GianfilippoBalestriero There are a few problems in your code. It'll take me a few minutes to address all of them. Hang on

Comment: @RaghavSood Thanks and don't worry, i'm here :)

Answer (score 2):

Okay... So there's more than one problem in this code, so I'm going to tackle it point by point.

**1. You're not launching an Activity the correct way**

To start `CoreGame`, you need to use an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) along the lines of:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CoreGame.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will run the Activity, and Android will call `CoreGame.onCreate()`. You do not need to call the constructor etc. Any thing you'd do in the constructor, should be done in the `onCreate()` or `onStart()` methods.

Now to your second problem

**2. You're going to end up with an NPE after you fix the Intent bit**

I'm not sure which class the posted `onCreate()` is in, so I'm going to split this into the two scenarios:

**Scenario 1: Posted onCreate() belongs to Game**

In this case, when you replace the `new CoreGame` lines with the `Intent` launching method, you'll still get a `NullPointerException` when you try to use `findViewById()`. This is because you only called `setContentView()` in the `Game` Activity, and now you'll be trying to access the `Views` from a different `Activity`. To fix this, you'll have to call `setContentView()` in `CoreGame` as well.

**Scenario 2: Posted onCreate() belongs to CoreGame**

In this case, you can remove these two lines entirely:

```
core = new CoreGame(this);
core.runCoreGame();
```

Instead, simply calling `runCoreGame()` should suffice

Comment: Wow... thx for your reply! I try this, just a moment :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this, this is the correct way of initializing and creating object.

```
 RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout);
```

Comment: While correct, it doesn't address the NPE.

Answer (score -2):

Correct me if I am wrong, but it looks like you are attempting to either

1. Declare a variable, but you have () around the type. That should give you an error message when compiling.
2. Using casting to get an property of the variable, which it may not have. Is `layout` actually `RelativeLayout` object?

My money is on the second option. You will get an exception if the object is not of the correct class, which is why casting may sound right. It is a simply line of thought that I had when I was still learning Java and Objective-C: "If it is not the correct type, I can cast to *make* it the correct type". Put simply, no. What you seem to be doing here is attempting to get/set a property from something that does not have that property, so the function returns `nil` or `null`. In Java, those are to be avoided at all costs if I am not mistaken.

You can fix this by declaring `layout` like this:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout);
```

That makes it the correct type, so it can properly receive any and all information. Now, I am new to Java and the Android SDKs, but I still have a recommendation: try to learn Java and get comfortable with it before you attempt to build a real application with it. You are obviously, unfortunately, not entirely familiar with the language and it's idiosyncrasies. If I am wrong, it is probably because I am confused. You really should post the code that shows the declaration of `layout` so we can see any potential problems there.

Edit: as AedonEtLIRA said in the comment to you, you should be doing this elsewhere anyway. Unless you *really* know *exactly* what you are doing, putting that kind of code into the constructor is very dangerous. Even if the application appears to be fine afterwards, that kind of thing can cause it to run more slowly and be much more volatile. Other code could cause it to crash for no apparent reason. This is because it can create zombies and "dead memory" in the application, which can cause problems when memory is needed for other activities.

Comment: Why the down vote? What did I mess up?

Comment: If layout where not a RelativeLayout, or a class derived there from, the exception would be ClassCastException.  The line quoted is nothing to do with "getting a property".  Looks like you are guessing for the rep points which is probably why the downvote.

Comment: @Simon Just to clear it up, I _am_ guessing, but not for the rep. The guess is based on the fact that I have no idea about the Android SDKs, but I do know a thing or two about Java and I have made a similar mistake myself. However, you are correct about the `ClassCastExecption`, and I will admit that I was wrong. Either way, I hope some of my points where correct and useful.